# Piping in Python like R - adding rank

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
Feature RFI
col1    1.8
col2    1.1
col3    2.1
col4    2.8
col5    0.3
```

How can I get the following output in one line?

```
Rank Feature RFI
3    col1    1.8
4    col2    1.1
2    col3    2.1
1    col4    2.8
5    col5    0.3
```

I have the following code to sort:

```
df.sort_values('RFI', ascending = True)
```

But I want to keep adding to this line with the dot operator to add this rank column similar to the pipe operator in R.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Feature": ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"],
        "RFI": [1.8, 1.1, 2.1, 2.8, 0.3],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df["Rank"] = (
    df.sort_values("RFI", ascending=False)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .sort_values("Feature", ascending=True)
    .index
    + 1
)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
  Feature  RFI  Rank
0    col1  1.8     3
1    col2  1.1     4
2    col3  2.1     2
3    col4  2.8     1
4    col5  0.3     5
```